# not able to load .mp3 format audio. Failed loading libmpg123.dll

Tags: python, dll, pygame, mp3, lib

I'm trying to import an .mp3 audio file for my background music and I receive the following error:
`pygame.error: Failed loading libmpg123.dll: The specified module could not be found.'''`
This happened after tried to turn my pygame script into a .exe using pyinstaller and it was fine before.
I've tried downloading and installing libmpg123.dll on my game file, python directory, dll folder and some other folders. aslo tried cleaning registry and reinstalling pygame.
full error:

````
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 17, in <module>
pygame.error: Failed loading libmpg123.dll: The specified module could not be found. ```
````

Comment: Try using another file format, like `.wav`. `.mp3` is a compressed format, which reduces the quality.

Comment: .wav files take too much space. I can do as you say but in the end I still need to be able to use .mp3 format files. any idea how I could fix the issue mentioned above?

Comment: You can convert your `.mp3` file into a `.wav` of lower quality, or use a larger storage space. From the pygame documentation: "*Be aware that MP3 support is limited. On some systems an unsupported format can crash the program, e.g. Debian Linux. Consider using OGG instead.*"